# Binomial Expansion of $(a-b)^n$ Find value of $\frac ab$.

Tags: binomial-theorem

Q: In the binomial expansion of $(a-b)^n, n\geq 5$, the sum of the $5$th and $6$th term is $0$. Find the value of $\frac{a}{b}$.

I had found 5th and 6th term. Which is:

- 5th term: $\binom{n}4\cdot a^{n-4} \cdot b^4$
- 6th term: $\binom{n}5 \cdot a^{n-5} \cdot -b^5$

I don't know how to proceed further. Please don't post answers directly, help me with some steps first.

The answer is: (n-4)/5

Comment: Note

$$b^{-n}(a-b)^n=\left({a\over b}-1\right)^n$$

Comment: You forgot the signs in the terms.

Comment: You also need to assume $a,b\neq 0$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, I have corrected the signs. so, now term 5th - 6th = 0. How to cancel out other terms, so that to get a/b?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews a,b ≠ 0? Didn't get that.

Comment: If, for example, $a=0$, and $n>5$, then the two terms are both zero so they sum to zero. But then $\frac{a}{b}=0$, obviously. If $b=0$, again, they are the same, and $\frac{a}{b}$ is not defined.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Obviously. they can't be zero, otherwise in either cases the terms will be not defined or be 0. I get that. But, still I couldn't visualize how to proceed further. What should I do with those two terms?

Comment: You said, "a,b\neq 0?" So I thought that was confusing you. I was simply indicating there were things wrong with the question as posted.

Comment: I thought you were indicating me hints on that "a/b not equal to 0" part. Sorry for the little confusion. I have checked the question, there is no fault. What should I do next?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you tried simply writing the equation $$\binom{n}{4} a^{n-4} b^4 - \binom{n}{5} a^{n-5} b^5 = 0$$ and doing all of the simplifications you can? (note that you had the sign wrong on the sixth term)

Comment: @Hurkyl I had fixed that error. Finally I had come to a/b = (n-4)!/5(n-5)! I really had no experience how to solve further.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: equalize the two expressions that you have already found for the $5^{th}$ and $6^{th}$ terms, and solve the resulting equation for $\frac{a}{b}$. In doing this, write the binomial numbers using factorials.

Comment: And so I have come to, a/b = nC5/nC4. How to solve further?

Comment: You arrive to $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\binom{n}5} {\binom{n}4}$. Now express the binomial numbers using factorials: remind that $\binom{n}k=\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: a/b = (n-4)!/5(n-5)! .. I haven't learnt how to solve them further. Can you guide me through?

Comment: $$\frac{\binom {n}5}{ \binom {n}4}= \frac {n!}{5!(n-5)!} \frac {4!(n-4)!}{n!}=\frac {4!}{5!} \frac {(n-4)!}{(n-5)!}=\frac {n-4}{5}$$

Comment: I get 4!/5! = 1/5. But How (n-4)!/(n-5)! = n-4? I seriously had no experience on that. This is now the only part which is confusing me a lot. Please help me with that.

Comment: @Swetank You should figure this part out yourself.  I recommend plugging in $n=6$ to see what is going on.  If it's not clear, try $n=7$.  If it's still not clear, try $n=8$.  If you're still stuck by the time you get to $n=20$, let us know and we'll help you further. :)

Comment: You have $(n-4)!=1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdot 4....  \cdot (n-4)$. On the other hand, you also have $(n-5)!=1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdot 4.... \cdot (n-5)$. In the ratio $(n-4)!/(n-5)!$, all terms simplify except the term $n-4$, which is contained in $(n-4)!$ but not in $(n-5)!$.

Comment: Hi Swetank, was all ok with the solution?